# bug in firefox and internet explorer with jquery fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css, debugging

Hey fellow developers,

I have been working on a fixed header that snaps into place with a top fixed header on scroll.

it works on chrome, but doesnt work on interent explorer or firefox.

Any help would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f95sW/4/

```
var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")
var additionalPixels = 50;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
        $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is `$('body').scrollTop()`

simply replace `$('body').scrollTop()` with `$(document).scrollTop()`

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/11/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have update the code with some extra features but having the same problem, can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/14/

Comment: one thing no quotes around document.....and only $('body').scrollTop() needs to be replaced.Have a look at my demo in answer\

Comment: Since your reported issue is fixed.I would recommend to accept this answer and open another question with new issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `$('body').scrollTop()` use `$(this).scrollTop()` i.e `$(window).scrollTop()`

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
        $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/f95sW/12/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have update the code with some extra features but having the same problem, can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/14/

Comment: I think it was better to use $(this).scrollTop() instead of $(document).scrollTop()