# Sticky/fixed header doesn't work in Firefox and Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, firefox

I've been working on a header that fixates when user scrolls to certain amount of pixels.

It works on Chrome, but it doesn't work at all on Firefox and Android default browser. I suspect it has something to do with the `scrollTop`, but I'm not sure what.

Here is my demo and code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xaliber/Y5xeZ/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var floatheader = $('#telunjuk-category').height()
            + parseInt($('#telunjuk-category').css('padding'))
            + parseInt($('#telunjuk-category').css('borderWidth')); // height of <header>
    var whitebarandsearchbar = 68 + $('.ui-listview-filter.ui-bar-c').height()  
            + parseInt($('.ui-listview-filter.ui-bar-c').css('padding'))
            + parseInt($('.ui-listview-filter.ui-bar-c').css('borderWidth'));

    if (top > floatheader) // height of float header
        $(function() {
            $('#categorypage #telunjuk-titlebar').addClass('stick');
            $('#categorypage .ui-listview-filter.ui-bar-c ').addClass('stick'); 
            $('#categorypage').css("padding-top", whitebarandsearchbar); 
        })
    else {
        $('#categorypage').removeAttr('style');
        $('#categorypage .ui-listview-filter.ui-bar-c').removeClass('stick');
        $('#categorypage #telunjuk-titlebar').removeClass('stick');
    }
});
```

It uses several variables because the `<header>` (that is stored in `floatheader`) changes height with different screen size. So does the search form (that is stored in `whitebarandsearchbar` along with `#telunjuk-titlebar`).

I have tried to change `$(window).scrollTop()` to `$(document).scrollTop()` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269797/651170). I also have tried the fix suggested [in this post](http://blog.c-krylatov.com/2013/05/05/make-sure-that-scrolls-jquery-event-will-work-everywhere/). But it still doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

`#telunjuk-category` doesn't have either a CSS value for `padding` nor for the `borderWidth`. So the return value of `$('#telunjuk-category').css('padding')` is  – nothing. While Chrome just parses an empty value to a `0`, Firefox apparently return `NaN`. That's why it's not working in the current version.

As a solution you might be best of to ditch your custom addition of all CSS values for jQuery's [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) function. This function already includes all the paddings & borders (and even margins if you want to).

So

```
var floatheader = $('#telunjuk-category').height()
            + parseInt($('#telunjuk-category').css('padding'))
            + parseInt($('#telunjuk-category').css('borderWidth'));
```

becomes

```
var floatheader = $('#telunjuk-category').outerHeight();
```

The same should be done for `whitebarandsearchbar`.

Note: This solution does work in Firefox, I can't test on Android but there some general issues with `position:fixed;` on Android: http://caniuse.com/css-fixed